# What to do with a .git directory?

Tags: git

I got a .git directory for me to work on, supposedly containing files and data to run.

I only a see a bunch of directories (branches, hooks, info, objects, refs) and some files (config, description, HEAD), but can't figure out what to do with them.

I'm assuming I should somehow link it with GitHub, except I have no idea how.

Comment: Read a git tutorial? There is lots of information on the web.

Comment: How/where did you get that `.git` directory?

Comment: @ytrewq So why don't you ask that co-worker how to work with it?

Comment: You wouldn't appear dumb if you've never worked with Git and ask about at least where to start. Don't be afraid to ask questions. Also, spend some time and read ProGit book (available for free at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to understand how Git works. Read at least chapters 1-3, don't try to learn Git by trial and error. Also, don't expect Git to be logical and user-friendly, just spend some time to read a book.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suppose what you got is a *bare repository*.
In order get the files out of it, you must create a non-bare clone.

Assuming that the directory you have mentioned is located at `/path/to/my/repository.git`, then by running the following command in a terminal:

```
git clone /path/to/my/repository.git /output/directory
```

you will find the contents of the repository in `/output/directory/`.

(You have to replace the directory paths with actual paths on your computer.)

Answer (score 2):

You should install GIT to use the GIT repository. Get it here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

After you download and install it. you can open a CMD and type

```
git branch --list
```

to see what branches are in the repo. and run

```
git checkout [branchename]
```

to build the branch filesystem.

To push to a remote, type

```
git remote add origin <your repository address>
```

and to push to your git repo:

```
git push origin --all
```

Comment: did you run the cmd in the folder the .git dir is in? You can first try to initialise the repository by running git init.

Answer (score 1):

The `.git` directory should stay inside your project directory. If all you have is the `.git` directory then create a new directory to store the project and move the `.git` directory into it.

Then open a console, `cd` to the project directory and run:

```
git checkout master
```

`master` is the usual name of the main branch in a Git repository, but this is just a convention, Git doesn't enforce the name in any way.

If if doesn't work you can try:

```
git branch -a
```

to list all the branches of the repo. Then pick a branch and run `git checkout` using its name as argument.

If you never worked with Git, reading the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a good starting point. After you understand the concepts, use `git help <command>` to learn the exact parameters and switches to run `git <command>`. Or read them on the [online documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs).

**Update:**

You say in a comment: *"co-worker just gave me the location of the directory on the server"*. The co-worker probably gave you the URL of the central repository. If this is the case then create an empty directory for the project, `cd` into it and run:

```
git clone <url-of-the-repository> .
```

Replace  with the actual URL provided by your co-worker.

When the cloning completes, use [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to see the branches, [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to check a branch out in order to work on the code, [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)[`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) to prepare a commit, [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) to do the commit, [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)/[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) to get the most recent changes from the upstream repository into your local repository, [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to send your changes to the upstream repository, [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to inspect the repository history and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Don't touch yourself your .git directory if you dont know what you are doing !! use git commands instead.

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

The command you are looking for is:

`git remote add origin <repository_address>`